# Focus event not working in HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML code is

```
<body>
    <form name="contactus" id='contactus' action="test1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="Tab" id="Tab">
        <div class="row underlinDv">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                Your Email :
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input maxlength="100" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" name="UEmailLogin" id="UEmailLogin" minlength="3">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--18-->
        <div class="row underlinDv">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-offset-4">
                <input type="submit" id="demo2GetTags" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Submit" onclick='search()' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
    function search() {
        var Tab = document.getElementById("Tab").value;
        alert(Tab);
        var Eamillogin = document.getElementById("UEmailLogin").value;
        if (Eamillogin == "") {
            alert("please enter email");
            Eamillogin.focus();
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

When I click on submit button, JavaScript alert shows "please enter email". It works fine. But `Eamillogin.focus();` not working. After showing alert, the form automatically direct to test1.php page.Pointer not focus on Email. How to correct it?

Comment: What Tushar has answered + don't use alerts for debugging, it messes up the focusing order. You can use `console.log` instead. Also, you've to cancel the submission, if you don't want to submit the form, which reloads the page as server response.

Answer (score 1):

`Eamillogin` variable contains the value of the `#UEmailLogin` element.

To set the focus on the element, use `element.focus();`

Here's updated code

```
var Eamillogin = document.getElementById("UEmailLogin"); // Removed .value from here
if (Eamillogin.value === "") {     // Added .value here
    alert("please enter email");
    Eamillogin.focus();            // Focus element
}
```

```js
function search() {
  var Tab = document.getElementById("Tab").value;

  var Eamillogin = document.getElementById("UEmailLogin");
  if (Eamillogin.value === "") {
    alert("please enter email");
    Eamillogin.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="contactus" id='contactus' action="test1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" value="2" name="Tab" id="Tab">
  <div class="row underlinDv">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Your Email :
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input maxlength="100" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email" name="UEmailLogin" id="UEmailLogin" minlength="3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--18-->
  <div class="row underlinDv">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-offset-4">
      <input type="submit" id="demo2GetTags" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Submit" onclick='search()' />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: When I remove <form name="contactus" id='contactus' action="test1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> its working fine. But when i use form elements pointer does not relay on form, it redirect to test1.php page

Comment: @Nidhi To cancel form submission on invalid form values, use `return search()` on the `onsubmit` or `onclick` of submit button and add `return false;` from the handler to stop form from submitting. See [How to prevent form from being submitted?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3350247)